# Мне нужно срезать цифры после запятой Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Мне надо именно не сократить число, а срезать его

Подскажите пожалуйста как это сделать

Например было **0.12**, а должно стать **0**

Comment: попробуйте так `int(0.12)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

вариантов несколько:

```
a = int(x)
```

если число больше нуля, то

```
import math
a = math.floor(x)
```

если число меньше нуля, то

```
import math
a = math.ceil(x)
```

ну и ряд извратов:

```
a = float(f"{x:.0f}")
```

или

```
import math
a = math.modf(x)[1]
```

P.S.

если же вам именно получить строку (например, чтобы вывести на экран), тогда

```
text = f"{x:.0f}"
```

или

```
text = format(x, ".0f")
```

Answer (score 3):

Я бы сделал так:

```
import re 
b = 0.123
a = re.sub('\.\d+', '', str(b))
print(int(a))
```

Answer (score 2):

Можно так:ᅠᅠᅠᅠᅠᅠᅠᅠᅠ

```
int(ЧИСЛО)
```